# how to group by in a array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, group-by

I have a array of hashes

and I need to be able to group them by users.

```
      order = Order.find(options[:order_id])
      shipments = order.shipments.select {|shipment| shipment["roundtrip_shipment"] == nil }.collect {|o| {
        id: o.id,
        user_id: o.user_id,
        ...
      } }
```

I am having some problems in making a group by in the array.

I have tried to do `shipments = order.shipments.group_by { |shipment| shipment[:user_id] }.count`

but this always returns 1 when I know that have 2 users here
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do as follow:

```
order = Order.find(options[:order_id])
shipments = order.shipments.where.not(roundtrip_shipment: nil).group_by(&:user_id).collect {|x,y| {x => y.map(&:id)} }
```